# "Application was stopped..." during SQLiteOpenHelper creation

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem when I want to start a new activity wchich contains a reference to object extending SQLiteOpenHelper.

This is how I sart my activity:

```
// Listener for button
class LoginButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MasterUserActivity.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

My new activity:

```
// I will be implementing ListView in here
public class MasterUserActivity extends ListActivity  {

    private DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.master_user);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MasterUserActivity.this, "It works :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

    }

}
```

And my DBHandler class:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHandler(Context contex) {
        super(contex, "bankapplication.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE users ( login TEXT, password TEXT, name TEXT, "
                + "phone TEXT, country TEXT, balance TEXT)";
        database.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users";
        database.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

It works fine when I comment out `private DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);`

What is wrong in here ?

Comment: Show us your stacktrace.

Comment: You can't do this in the declaration area: `private DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);` You have to break it into two statements. And put the initialization into `onCreate()`

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Using the "this" keyword in member initialization is a clear sign you should read about the basics of java before using a framework written in java...

Comment: Initialize dbHandler = new DBHandler(this); in onCreate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing the error :

```
private DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);
```

You can not call new while declaring variable, instead initialize inside onCreate method of your activity.

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Can you post error details which you are getting ?